# Reduce lines of code needed to format cells?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am trying to reduce the amount of lines needed to add borders (and other formatting) to a cell.

Here's the code that will create a border around cell A1:

```
Sub test2()
Dim cel As Range


Set cel = Range("A1")
With cel.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With cel.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With cel.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With cel.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
End Sub
```

As you can see, these `With` blocks take up some space.  For no real reason other than keeping my code "tight" and so I don't have to scroll so much, I was wondering if I could make this more compact.  I was thinking using an array, but it doesn't work:

```
Sub test()
Dim arr()
Dim i As Integer
ReDim arr(1 To 4)
Dim cel As Range

Set cel = Range("A1")
arr = Array("xlEdgeTop", "xlEdgeBottom", "xlEdgeRight", "xlEdgeLeft")
For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
With cel.Borders(arr(i))
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With

Next i
End Sub
```

(Note: the error occurs on line `With cel.Borders(arr(i))`, "Run-Time Error '13': Type mismatch".)

Anyone have any ideas on shortening the above, or is that just something I'm going to have to live with?

Comment: I can't think of anything off the top of my head.  Formatting has always been many lines of code for me.

Comment: @cyboashu has the answer, but FYI `Array("xlEdgeTop", "xlEdgeBottom", "xlEdgeRight", "xlEdgeLeft")` should be `Array(xlEdgeTop, xlEdgeBottom, xlEdgeRight, xlEdgeLeft)`  Those are numeric constants, not strings.

Comment: @TimWilliams - aha! That does it :D  I assume then that things like `xlEnd`, etc. are also constants and could be used in the same way?

Comment: @BruceWayne: Yes all this similar names are constants in VBA and you can use them as variants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. border names are constants, just define the array without apostrophes.
2. you can refer to the whole borders collection as one, do not specify any border, so just use `with Selection.borders...` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837809.aspx)

*(the two suggestions work independently)*

Comment: That's the key, "Border names are constants, just define the array without apostrophes".  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you just want black border (usually the default color scheme) this much code will do:

```
With Selection.Borders()
 .LineStyle = xlContinuous
End With
```

In `Selection.Borders()` all you need to is skip the enumeration. Its defaulted to all four sides. Rest of the properties you can change as needed.

Comment: Thanks for this - I realize that now, but mainly my question was about using arrays with different Excel constants.  But again, this helps!